# Access geodatabase simultaneously by several users

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, esri-geodatabase, versioning

We have a requirement to edit a Geodatabase simultaneously by several users.

We have several GIS specialists who are loading the data at the same time and each time we have to copy paste the data from different servers onto one geodatabase. I have tried several options such as ArcSDE basic edition and ArcSDE enterprise all the options are very expensive.

Is there any other way to access the geodatabase at the same time by several users?

Comment: Have you tried versioning? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-versioning.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [Distributed Geodatabases](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/understanding-distributed-data.htm). It would take some coordination and management but might get you what you need.